# Referencing a CSV File in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I'm trying to reference a `.csv` file that was exported from Outlook... My code I've attempted with is giving the error `Run-time error '424': Object Required`

I'm guessing it's because it's not in a `.xls`, `.xlsm` etc. format? How would I reference this as a `Worksheet`?

```
Sub test1()

    Dim PrimaryWB As Workbook
    Dim DataWS As Worksheets
    Set PrimaryWB = ThisWorkbook
    Set DataWS = Active.Worksheet

    Debug.Print PrimaryWB.Name
    Debug.Print DataWS.Name

End Sub
```

My active window is the `.csv` file and `ThisWorkbook` is referencing my Workbook I want to copy the data to. The error is happening on `Set DataWS = Active.Worksheet`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Set DataWS = Active.Worksheet` is invalid syntax. The correct sytnax is `Set DataWS = ActiveSheet`

However, using `ActiveSheet` can have many traps, although in a few select cases it's absolutely necessary. This is not one of them.

See this fully qualified code that will ensure everything is set to what you intend.

```
Sub test1()

    Dim PrimaryWB As Workbook
    Dim DataWB As Workbook
    Set PrimaryWB = ThisWorkbook
    Set DataWB = Workbooks("myCSV.csv") 'Change name as needed

    Dim DataWS as Worksheet
    Set DataWS = DataWB.Sheets(1) 'CSV only has one sheet, so index is okay

    Debug.Print PrimaryWB.Name
    Debug.Print DataWS.Name

End Sub
```

Comment: Can this work with a pathname to it as well? I tried referencing it with a `C:\PATH\test.csv` and it saying `Out of range` however when I exclude the path is works fine. It'd be ideal if I could get it to work with a pathname as well

Comment: @Maldred - The only way a path name will work is if the file is already closed. If that is the case use `Set DataWB = Workbooks.Open("C:\PATH\test.csv")`

Comment: This is great and works perfect! I've got one last question, how would I access this data without opening the `.csv` file? Or would it be best to just close it after I'm done with it?